# Member by member assignment of different classes based on the same template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Say that one has two classes which are different, but are somewhat "equivalent" in their purpose, so they have the same members, and one can be assigned by the other:

```cpp
struct Pure
{
    QString name;
    int age = 18;
};

struct Observable
{
    QProperty<QString> name;
    QProperty<int> age {18};
    void operator=(const Pure& other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        age = other.age;
    }
};
```

`QProperty` is a [template class from Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qproperty.html), but I think the question is Qt-independent, as it would apply to any other `template <typename T> class Foo` which has a conversion/assignment to/from `T`.

The question is how to avoid the duplication, so one cannot so easily add or remove a member from one class and forget doing it on the other, while still retaining the possibility of assigning an object of one class to another.

I've attempted several things with templates, and this seems the most promising:

```cpp
// Adding two helpers only available in C++ 20 for convenience.
template<typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };    
template<typename T>
using type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;

template<template<typename T> typename T>
struct State
{
    T<QString> name;
    T<int> age;

//    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<QProperty<class X>, T>>
//    operator=(const State<type_identity_t>& other)
//    {
//        name = other.name;
//        age = other.age;
//    }
};

int main()
{
    State<type_identity_t> state;
    state.age = 42;
    State<QProperty> observableState;
    observableState = state; // Desired use. Fails to compile without operator=
}
```

The commented out code doesn't compile (error: use of template template parameter 'T' requires template arguments), with the error at the `T` at the end of the first commented line, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: C++ is not an answer to everything. List all class members and their types in a separate file in some structured format like XML or YAML, and write a simple script to generate C++ code for both classes. Integrate this into your build system.

Comment: I know that this is a possibility. I use code generation often, as it's common in Qt or when you need IPC/RPC, etc. Do you think using templates is plain not possible, though?

Comment: Doing it semi-automatically as a first step (there is no inspection yet): Pure could statically check whether Observable has the two members defined. Observable checks it indirectly within the assignment operator.

Comment: The current state of C++ does not allow for something like this to be implemented entirely in C++ itself.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that a solution based on the metaclasses proposal would save all the boilerplate. But I was just settling down on having one template and the duplication *only* on the `operator=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `std::is_same<QProperty<class X>, T>`, because this is trying to pass `T` as the second argument to `is_same`, but it's a template and `is_same` is expecting a type.

You can make a `is_same`-like trait that takes template classes instead:

```cpp
template<template<typename...> class A, template<typename...> class B>
struct is_same_template_class : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class T>
struct is_same_template_class<T, T> : std::true_type {};

// use `is_same_template_class<T, QProperty>`
```

---

Currently, there doesn't seem to be a reason to limit what your `operator=` can do. Why not something like:

```cpp
template<template<typename> class T>
struct State
{
    T<QString> name;
    T<int> age;

    template<template<typename> class U>
    State& operator=(const State<U>& other)
    {
        name = other.name;
        age = other.age;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

And I am not familiar with QT, but it seems like `using Observable = QProperty<Pure>;` may also work if you refactor some of your logic.

Comment: Wonderful response, TVM! Indeed, not constraining `operator=` is probably the best option. I was too set on my way to provide it only when needed. I'm not too used to writing templates. I knew that the arguments to is_same were wrong, but I thought I could just express what I wanted by slapping more template/typename keywords. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, and `QProperty<T>` works with copy constructible/assignable types like `Pure` here, indeed, but then you can *only* subscribe to the whole compound type being changed. I wanted to know if it was possible to be more granular, member by member. Now I can. :)